# Text to Image with boxes using PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I tried to design a text to image box so that it behaves in the following way:

text wraps in the box as I type, meaning when the line exceeds the width of box it shrinks to the next line. 
also I m able to align it horizontally and vertically as in the picture.

Do you know any library or any resource.???

Thanks in advance: 
[image]

Comment: What language or environment? On the face of it this doesn't seem like an image processing question.

Comment: You say you tried, but you haven't included your code.  Tell us what you need help with!